# License of library used by one library include in my project

Tags: licensing, libraries

I am developing a small project to sell and I have used several Java libraries, mostly with LGPL or Apache 2.

And I have one question, for example, I am using jasypt, wich is an Apache 2 license library, but this requires the commons collections library, also Apache 2.

Do I need to put in my license form the common collections library?.

```
Apache 2.0 License
Used in  Apache Commons Codec version 1.10 , Joda-Time version 2.6 , Xerial Sqlite JDBC version 3.8.7 and Jasypt version 1.9.2

<LICENSE GOES HERE>

BSD License
Used in  MigLayout version Swing 4.2 and JDatePicker version 1.3.4

<LICENSE GOES HERE>

LGPL 2.1 LICENSE
Used in PortableRXTX and RXTX version 2.2-pre2

<LICENSE GOES HERE>
```

Also the LGPL and the Apache force me to put the source code and the modifications, but if I have used the binaries without compiling or modifiying anything, Do I need to include the source? If I need could I post a link to githubs repos with the latest version of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your license form, you should mention all libraries that you are distributing as part of your application.
Libraries that you use but not distribute (for example, because you assume they will be already installed as they are commonly part of the JRE/runtime environment) you can mention but without license details.

Making it a habit to include all libraries you distribute with full license details makes it harder to miss one where the license requires that is is mentioned also in the application.
Mentioning the dependencies that you don't distribute is mostly a courtesy to their authors and can be a help to people with an unusual setup that happen to miss one. Mentioning licenses for these is a bit misleading, because your users might have a different version under a different license.

---

Technically the LGPLv2 requires that if you provide binaries, that you also must provide the source code.
However, if you did not make any changes to the code, then it is in practice sufficient to provide a link to the original project where you got your binaries/sources from.

The Apache 2 license does not require you to distribute the source of unmodified libraries, but here it is also a gesture of goodwill to provide a link to the original project for those that want to retrieve the sources.

Often, these links are provided together with the license information for the libraries.